# UriComponentsBuilder behaves differently for springboot 2.3.x and 2.4.x

Tags: spring-boot

I am using below Code for both springboot 2.3.x and 2.4.x:-
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://localhost:56429ecomp/mso/catalog/v2/serviceVnfs");

ResponseEntity response =
restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

It works fine for springboot 2.3.x and builder.toUriString() returns -http://localhost:56429/ecomp/mso/catalog/v2/serviceVnfs (Adds a slash automatically).

But for 2.4.x version I get error- NumberFormatException For input string: "56429ecomp".

I know I can add a slash and fix this, but want to know why It behaves so.